# Is this possible with less code repetition

Tags: scala

We're using case classes to represent the JSON objects transferred between the client and server. It's been working great except for one sticking point we've been living with for quite a while now and I wonder if anyone has a clever way around it.

Let's say I have a user object that has id, first name, last name and email address. Once a user has been saved to the database, he has an id (`Int`) assigned to him, so for all communication between the client and server dealing with existing users, the id is a required field. In fact, there is only one case when the id field is not required and that's when the user is first being saved. The way we currently deal with this is with a case class that looks like this:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], firstName: String, lastName: String, email:String)
```

In all cases except the initial save, that id is `Some` and for the initial save id is always `None` so we find ourselves using `id.getOrElse(0)` quite often. (Sometimes we'll do a `.get` but it feels dirty.)

What I would love to have is an object with an `id: Int` field for existing users and an object with no id field at all for new users, but without declaring all the other fields twice in two separate case classes.  However, I'm not seeing a way to do that conveniently. I'm also not fond of using a 'magic' number for the id field of new users.

Does anyone have a better solution to this issue?

Comment: one of the approaches is to use inheritance, ie class User has no id, but InitializedUser extends from User add this one field

Comment: Same problem exists in databases.  Look for the talk "Pure Functional Database Programming with Fixpoint Types" by Rob Norris.

Comment: @Lashane I don't think that helps. The subclass would have to re-declare the other fields for the constructor to populate the superclass. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @TimGautier I suppose you're speaking about constructor arguments, not really about fields, as you don't have to re-declared all class fields

Comment: @Lashane I'm thinking of case classes where the constructor arguments are also the property declarations. Regardless, I'm trying to avoid solving this by listing out most of the names and types multiple times. The example I gave is trivial, but this will be for a large number of very large case classes.

Comment: @ashawley That's an excellent video and has some really good info in it. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case class User[+IdOpt <: Option[Int]](idOpt: IdOpt, firstName: String, lastName: String, email:String)
object User {
  // Type aliases for convenience and code readability
  type New = User[None.type]
  type Saved = User[Some[Int]]
  type Value = User[Option[Int]] // New or Saved

  implicit class SavedOps(val user: Saved) extends AnyVal {
    def id: Int = user.idOpt.get
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
scala> val billNew = User(None, "Bill", "Gate", "bill@microsoft.com")
billNew: User[None.type] = User(None,Bill,Gate,bill@microsoft.com)

scala> billNew.id 
<console>:17: error: value id is not a member of User[None.type]
       billNew.id
               ^

scala> val billSaved = billNew.copy(idOpt = Some(1))
billSaved: User[Some[Int]] = User(Some(1),Bill,Gate,bill@microsoft.com)

scala> billSaved.id
res1: Int = 1
```

Comment: This is very interesting and gave me some ideas. It's not quite what I'm going with, but since this is where I got the ideas, I'll accept it as the answer and just post what I did as a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is what we ended up going with for now.

```
trait Resource[T <: Option[Int]] {
  def idOpt: T
}

object Resource {
  type IsSome = Some[Int]
  implicit class SomeOps[R <: Resource[IsSome]](val resource: R) {
    def id: Int = resource.idOpt.get
  }
}
```

This allows us to use it like this:

```
case class User[T <: Option[Int]](idOpt:T, firstName:String, lastName:String, email:String) extends Resource[T]
case class Company[T <: Option[Int]](idOpt:T, companyName: String) extends Resource[T]

val u1 = User(None, "Bubba", "Blue", "bubba@shrimp.com")
val u2 = User(Some(1), "Forrest", "Gump", "forrest@shrimp.com")
u1.id // <-- won't compile
u2.id // <-- compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a magic number is not a terrible idea if you hide it from the user. in fact it is a common pattern, Slick uses it for example. You can just ignore the id value for the objects to be inserted.

So you can start by making the the constructor package private

```
 case class User private[db](id: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, email:String)
```

And then provide a companion object for users to create it without id

```
 object User{
   def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String): User = User(-1, firstName, lastName, email)
}
```

And now you can construct it as if id wasn't required

```
val user = User("first","last","email")
```

Comment: The thing I don't like about the magic number is that I have to either "know" whether or not the object I'm dealing with has a valid id, or I have to check if it's equal to the magic number. I've lost my type safety at that point because the type doesn't tell me if it's a new or existing user. Granted, I have the same problem with an optional id, but with the optional id the compiler won't let me get away with forgetting about the validity of the id.